# Unable to call public method of the base class from a child's instance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I wanted to try constructor inheritance in C++ and it worked fine. But then I found that I can't really call a method from the instance of **Daughter** *class*. Visual studio says

> the method Mother::ShowName is not available

even though it is public, which as far as I am concerned must be available from the child class. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
class Mother{

protected:
  char* name;

public :    
  Mother(char* _name){
      name = _name;
  }

  void ShowName(){
      cout << "my name is: " << name << endl;
  }
};


class Daughter : Mother{
public:
  Daughter(char* _name) : Mother(_name) {
  }
};

int main(){
  Daughter d1("Masha");
  d1.ShowName();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: the very first Class must be in non-capital to have a working example

Comment: That's right, it changed to capital accidentally when I copied it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`class Daughter : Mother` is `private` inheritance. `class` inheritance is like that by default.

`class Daughter : public Mother` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! Came from C#, only starting to see differences.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `public` inheritance:

```
class Daughter : public Mother
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to inherit the mother class using access specifier **public**. By default c++ treats it private.

Answer (score 2):

As Grigore pointed out, you should add 'public' explicitly.

F.Y.I, C++ standard addressed as following:

In the absence of an access-specifier for a base class, public is assumed when the derived class is defined with the class-key struct and private is assumed when the class is defined with the class-key class.